# New WebStorm 2019.3 is missing debug integration with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, debugging, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2019.3 and I seem to be missing automatic debug integration with TypeScript (node, or ts-node).

I had green debug circles in version like 2018. I do know that I can go to `Run -> edit configuration` and do a lot of manual steps (specifying the test name or filename) but it's so freaking inconvenient now.

Here's the example of how it was before and now (the 2nd screen is taken from PyCharm/python).

[image]

P.S. [Related IntelliJ topic](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006528060-New-Webstorm-is-missing-debug-integration-with-Typescript)

**The proof with WebStorm2018.2** (no, this is NOT ES-compatible code there're `:type` definitions :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Running *.ts* files from right-click menu had never been supported, as Node.js can't run Typescript directly, it has to be pre-compiled.

The easiest way to run TypeScript files from the IDE is using the [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node):

- Install *ts-node* using npm (`npm install -D ts-node typescript`).
- Create a new **Node.js** run/debug configuration.
- Add `--require ts-node/register` to the **Node parameters** field.
- In the **JavaScript file** field add `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$`.
- Save configuration.
- Use it to run (or debug) a file that is currently opened in the editor or selected in the **Project** view. You can do that using the icons on the navigation bar or **Run...** action.

If you need to pass any additional parameters to *ts-node* (e.g. `--project tsconfig.json`), you can add them to the **Application parameters** field in the run/debug configuration.

If you don't like installing any additional tools, you can use the built-in TypeScript compiler:

- Add *tsconfig.json* file to your project.
- Create a new **Node.js** run/debug configuration.
- In the **Before Launch** section, click **Add** and select **Compile TypeScript**.
- Select *tsconfig.json*.
- In the **JavaScript file** field you need to select the path to the compiled file.

  - If a compiled JavaScript lives next to its source, add `$FileRelativeDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js`
  - If files are saved in an output folder (preserving the folder structure), add the folder name before the pattern, e.g. `build/$FileRelativeDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js`
- Save configuration.
- Use it to run (or debug) a file that is currently opened in the editor or selected in the Project view.

It all works in WebStorm right now.

Note that running **Mocha** Typescript specs from file right-click menu/gutter is still supported - WebStorm 2019.3 auto-adds `--require ts-node/register` to such configurations:

[image]

Comment: Please see my edits, I didn't do any manual steps. That was the initial goal, I said that I know how to do it manually

Comment: in  WebStorm2018.2, you have your `.ts` file recognized as *Mocha* test. This feature is still available in 2019.3 for *Mocha* tests (see the updated answer). But a generic `.ts` file can't be run from the right-click menu, and it had never worked.

Comment: actually you can run it but you can't debug :( Weird I just found out that mocha test isn't available for all the projects.

Comment: debugging Mocha ts tests does work... Just as debugging .ts files pre-compiled and executed by Node.js